# Why is my build.xml file missing after adding android platform with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, ant, android-sdk-2.3

I've just upgraded Cordova from v4.1.2 to v5.0.0 like this:

```
npm install -g cordova@5.0.0
```

When I try to add an android platform the following command runs without any errors:

```
cordova platform add android@5.0.0
```

However it appears that they didn't run correctly since there are files missing in the newly-created `android` folder. I can see this because when I try to build using this command...

```
ant release -Dsdk.dir=/home/<my_dir>/android-sdk/
```

...I get the following error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I've checked and build.xml is indeed missing.

Those same commands used to work ok before the upgrade and the build.xml file was being created ok, so I've obviously missed something. Anyone got any ideas what?

**Extra Details** (in case they are helpful)

```
$ npm -v
1.3.10

$ node -v
v0.10.25

$ cordova -v
5.0.0

$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT: Stuff I've tried**

I've tried upgrading to a later version of Cordova (v6.0.0):

Steps:

1) Update Cordova: `npm install -g cordova@6.0.0`

2) Update Dependencies `sudo npm update -g`

3) Update Node using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677498/unable-to-install-latest-nodejs-version-on-ubuntu-14-04)

4) Add Android target android-23 `android update sdk -u -a -t android-23`

But sadly this doesn't fix the problem. When I run `cordova platform add android@5.0.0` the platform is added, but the build.xml file is still missing.

Comment: Why do you use cordova@5.0.0 ? Latest version is 6.4.0

Comment: I did try the latest version first and had a similar problem. So I'm just trying a smaller increment.

Answer (score 1):

In cordova-android 4, it started using Gradle as default for building the apps instead of ant.

I think cordova-android 5.0.0 had some problems with ant, you can try with 5.2.2 and check if it works.

Anyway, you don't need ant for building your app, you should use the Cordova CLI for that

`cordova build android --release` should create a signend .apk if you have a build.json file with the information needed (keystore, password), or you can provide them as params 
[More information about the build command](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-build-command)

Comment: I don't have a _build.json_ file either. Maybe that's part of the problem. Where should that come from?

Comment: you have to create it http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#using-buildjson

Answer (score 0):

I guess the cordova Cli version and Android version are two different things. Also as per the Cordova 6.0 release notes, it supports Android platform version 5.0. Pleae check out this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html)

hence you may have to install cordova 6.0 version inorder to add android platform version 5.0.0 This could be your issue. Please check out

Comment: I've just tried updating Cordova to v6.0.0. Now the add platform command gives this error "Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'". I guess something needs updating.

Comment: @Urbycoz u gotta update npm dependencies. Check out this link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/724863/how-can-i-fix-the-cannot-find-module-bplist-parser-error-with-phonegap

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Now I am getting a message saying node is out of date (It's currently on 0.10.25).

Comment: I've followed the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677498/unable-to-install-latest-nodejs-version-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install the next available node version (v4.6.2). Now I'm getting error `Error: Please install Android target: "android-23"`.

Comment: @Urbycoz now u gotta install android-23 version using android sdk manager. check out

Comment: Ok. I think this is the right command to do that: `android update sdk -u -a -t android-23`. I've done that now too. It's still crashing, but this time the error is: `/home/<username>/appbuilder/apps/<my_app_name>/platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins/SocialSharing.java:19: error: package org.apache.http.util does not exist
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;` It seems to be due my SocialSharing plugin being out-of-date. I'll update it.

Comment: It now adds the android platform without any errors. But the build.xml file is still missing.

Comment: @Urbycoz i m not sure which build.xml u r talking about as i dont see any build.xml file under my android platform folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129615/discussion-between-urbycoz-and-gandhi).

Comment: Not yet. I'm keen to try to get the old ant method working if I can- just to minimise any changes to our current process. I'll try the more up-to-date gradle method if I can't get it to work.